# Drupal Migrate sqlstate error

Tags: migrations

Can anyone tell me why I would get this error:

```
Migration MyData could not be constructed.                                                           [error]
    SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'sourceid1'
```

...from the following code:

```
class MyDataMigration extends Migrator{

    public function __construct($arguments){
        parent::__construct($arguments);
        $this->description = t('Imports data');

        // source
            $options = array(
                'header_rows'=>1,
                'delimiter'=>','
            );

            $uri = drupal_get_path('module', 'migrator') . "/includes/MyData.csv";
            $this->source = new MigrateSourceCSV($uri, array(), $options );

        // destination
            $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationNode('link');

        // map
            $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap(
                $this->machineName,
                array(
                    'user_id' => array(
                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'length' => 10,
                        'description' => t('User ID'),
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                        'default' => '',
                    ),
                    'page_id' => array(
                        'type' => 'int',
                        'length' => 10,
                        'description' => t('Page ID'),
                        'unsigned' => TRUE,
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                        'default' => 0,
                    )
                ),
                MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema()
            );
        }

}
```

...importing this sample data:

```
user_id,link_id,page_id,name,request,promote,position,status
LKSDET,11030,19600,Online Forms - Haringey,,NULL,NULL,Active
ASDFRE,3,21747,e-payments,,NULL,NULL,NULL
JYHGKI,4,19574,Directorates,,NULL,NULL,NULL
OOLPKH,5,19574,Directorates,,NULL,NULL,NULL
VBNGTY,108,21236,SAP Resources,,NULL,NULL,Active
QWERCF,1047,19640,Pay and Conditions,,NULL,NULL,NULL
LPOUIJ,12,21747,e-payments,,NULL,NULL,NULL
XCBGTY,13,21747,e-payments,,NULL,NULL,NULL
UJUIKU,10,21747,e-payments,,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

Comment: Did you tried to delete the default attribute in map constructor ('default' => '') like indicated in the error message ? because user_id can't be at the same time not null and with an empty default value !

Comment: @Boussettamoez: Hi.
Tried that and it made no difference.
Thanks for the suggestion.